# ADD Column ON UPDATE TIMESTAMP

Tags: oracle-11g, row-modification-time

I want to alter a table to include `modified` and `created` columns. However, I am having trouble with adding the `modified` column. I get the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

I was reading this Oracle document (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/timestamp-initialization.html) to get an example on how to properly write the `ON UPDATE` syntax

Here is my SQL.

```
ALTER TABLE FOOBAR
ADD (
  created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Why am I getting a missing right parenthesis error?

Comment: NB I wouldn't specify a default for `modified` so that it remains null when unmodified. And use a `for each row` trigger to set `:new.modified := systimestamp;` .

Comment: I wish oracle adds ON UPDATE ... so devs that has no option, and stuck with oracle due to corporate policy, can feel better :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the MySQL documentation, not the Oracle Database documentation.
There is no such clause in Oracle Datababase. 
Use a trigger. Here is an example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614233/is-there-an-automatic-modification-time-stamp-type-for-oracle-columns)

Comment: Oracle MySQL Database vs Oracle Database? And Googling `Oracle <SQL statement>` no longer always points to Oracle Database documentation but sometimes MySQL documentation links will be listed first. No wonder people are getting confused.

Comment: It's annoying :/ Though whacking the version number after Oracle is usually ok...